# Send error info from service to controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular service:

```
function postService($http, $log, settings) {
  return {
    get: function (pageNumber, pageSize) {    
      return $http.get(
        "/api/posts",
        { params: { pageNumber: pageNumber, pageSize: pageSize } }
      ).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      }, function (response) {
        $log.error("Service Error");
        return "Service Error";
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I return the data when everything is well ... But when there is an error I want the controller to know about it so it can show, for example, a message.

Then the controller is:

```
function PostListController($timeout, settings, postService) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.posts = [];
  vm.pagination = { pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 4 };

  vm.load(1, 4);

  vm.load = function (pageNumber, pageSize) {

    postService.get(pageNumber, pageSize)
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log("Controller Success");
        vm.posts = data;
      }, function (error) {
        console.log("Controller Error");
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
}
```

When I simulate an error on the service I see on the console:

```
"Server Error"
"Controller Success"
```

When it should be something like:

```
"Server Error"
"Controller Error"
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Should I have the following service instead?

```
function postService($http, $log, settings) {
  return {
    get: function (pageNumber, pageSize) {    
      return $http.get(
        "/api/posts",
        { params: { pageNumber: pageNumber, pageSize: pageSize } }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And let the controller handle the data or error in case that happens?

I was doing things this way by then on John Pappa Style guide I read:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#separate-data-calls

In this case the service handles it ... But it does not return any error in case that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider using `$q` promise and create a reject reason.

> $q.reject(reason). Creates a promise that is resolved as rejected with the specified reason.

```
function postService($http, $log, settings, $q) {
  return {
    get: function (pageNumber, pageSize) {    
      return $http.get(
        "/api/posts",
        { params: { pageNumber: pageNumber, pageSize: pageSize } }
      ).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      }, function (response) {
        $log.error("Service Error");
        return ($q.reject("Service Error"));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

#### In response you updated question:

You had mentioned that it is a style guide. Therefore, it is a personal preference. Personally, I would like to handle the error on service and controller side.

### Reason:

1. I can send the same error message when this service gets called and has an error. I don't need to write it to every single controllers when they are using this service. Remember Angular service is singleton.
2. I can handle the error in the service side before the error is passed to controller. This is very useful when you are encounter an issue that you need to load some data for a route before the controller is generated: typical usage with **ui-route** of the resolve problem.

Comment: I just added an update to my question ... I think what you suggesting is something similar to what I used to do ... Is it?

Comment: Usually it is much easier to just ask a new question, since you have more space to explain what the question is. Also, if you add info later, this confuses readers and nobody will come back to look at your changes/new questions.